# Open RichTextFile without using DialogBox

Tags: c#

I am writing an application in which mostly I have to retrieve or store some data to a textfile without using any dialog box. I have achieved the saving mechanism with the help of StackOverflow users, Thanks to everybody.

```
public void SaveIt(string parser)
{
    MessageBox.Show(parser);
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(parser);
    file.WriteLine(this.NotePad.Rtf);
    file.Close();
}
```

Now the problem is that I want the program to read from a file to a RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
this.NotePad.Rtf = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)
```

Comment: Would this preserve the formatting the text is saved in rtf file?

Comment: rtf is a text readable format. This operation reads the text from the file, preserving the rtf tags inside. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you

this.NotePad.LoadFile(@"E:\TT.rtf");

The code can throw Argument exception if the file format is different
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx